# What is the best way to call module based on the environment in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, module, config, environment

I have 2 environments in **Angular 2**: `dev` and `prod`. I want to create an advanced authentication (includes other services from my project), but I want to create a dummy login in the `dev` environment.

I'm not an expert in **Angular**, but I think the best way to do this if I create 2 modules, for example: `Login` and `DummyLogin`, and the app calls the corresponding module based on the environment.

**My question**: Is this the right way of doing it and if so, how can I do this and is it safe enough for using it?

If there is a better solution what would be that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why do want to have a dummyLogin service etc. Do you know what would happen if you deployed that?  anyway have a look here maybe this will help http://tattoocoder.com/angular-cli-using-the-environment-option/

Comment: The main reason is because the login service not available in my local deployment, because it uses different services (its hard to explain it, but I can not login from localhost) :/ Now I have to hard code the changes if I want to push to master, or to develop at local.

Comment: well one solution would be to fake the return of the service cal to return a success call. but be careful when checking in your code.